# Livecycle - Pagination - Top of page

Tags: pagination, repeat, livecycle, subform, livecycle-designer

I got a problem.

I would like to have a repeating subform on the first bodypage("Sida1" bould one), that should repeat on the first masterpage(Page1). I want it to start at the top of the first master page all the time. But if I set it that way I think it might work, it gives me a white blank page at start and then work as intended(it start repeating subforms in the top of the masterpage (Page1)).

Seems like it will create one extra masterpage of the one you set it to, if you set it to be Top of page "Page1". It will create on master page to much. Atleast if you have those setting of the body page that is the first bodypage.

I don't have 10 reputaion to upload a images, so i will mark up how the hierarchy looks like:

- Form

  - (Master Pages)
    Page1
    Page2
    Page3
    //Body pages comes below this..
    -**Sida1**
    -Sida2
    -Sida3
    -(Variables)

Comment: LiveCycle does that if you set Sida1's master page explicitly, i.e. the layout mechanism automatically grabs and layouts the first masterpage. Remove the setting and, instead, set the overflow setting on the overflowing subform.

Comment: I don't really get how that would make it work. I have set "Sida1" is placed on "Top pf Page"Page1"" cause I need it to be on the top everytime one of "Sida1" is going to iterate more then once. So all of them i just place on the top of the masterpage, when they being placed out.

Could you try to evolve your answer to me? :D